# Calculadora C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms

**Intento hacer una calculadora para un proyecto de mi preparatoria, ya tengo una parte del codigo pero tengo un problema que aun me falta resolver.**

Necesito que cuando presione un operador matematico, y despues de colocar los dos numeros en la calculadora y presionar de nuevo el operador matematico, se muestre el resultado de esos dos numeros sin tener que presionar el igual a, por ejemplo, que cuando pongas 10+10+10, al poner el segundo +, se muestre el resultado en pantalla de la suma de 10 + 10 y el programa este preparado para poder seguir, gracias de antemano adjunto el codigo:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace calculadoracaifanes
{
    public partial class frm1 : Form
    {
        public enum Operacion { 
            NoDefinida = 0,
            Suma = 1,
            Resta = 2,
            Multiplicacion = 3,
            Division = 4
        }

        public frm1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Operacion operador = Operacion.NoDefinida;
        double a= 0;
        double b = 0;


        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private double HacerOperacion() {
            double resultado = 0;
            switch (operador) { 
                case Operacion.Suma:
                    resultado = a + b;
                    break;
                case Operacion.Resta:
                    resultado = a - b;
                    break;
                case Operacion.Multiplicacion:
                    resultado = a * b;
                    break;
                case Operacion.Division:
                    if (b == 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No se puede dividir entre 0");
                        txtres.Text = "0";
                    }
                    else {
                        resultado = a / b;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return resultado;

        }
        private void btnn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtres.Text == "0")
            {
                txtres.Text = "";
            }
            if (txtres.Text == "")
            {
                txtres.Text = "1";
            }
            else
            {
                txtres.Text = txtres.Text + "1";
            }
        }

        private void btnn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtres.Text == "0")
            {
                txtres.Text = "";
            }
            if (txtres.Text == "")
            {
                txtres.Text = "2";
            }
            else
            {
                txtres.Text = txtres.Text + "2";
            }
        }

        private void btnn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtres.Text == "0")
            {
                txtres.Text = "";
            }
            if (txtres.Text == "")
            {
                txtres.Text = "3";
            }
            else
            {
                txtres.Text = txtres.Text + "3";
            }
        }

        private void btnn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtres.Text == "0")
            {
                txtres.Text = "";
            }
            if (txtres.Text == "")
            {
                txtres.Text = "4";
            }
            else
            {
                txtres.Text = txtres.Text + "4";
            }
        }

        private void btnn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtres.Text == "0")
            {
                txtres.Text = "";
            }
            if (txtres.Text == "")
            {
                txtres.Text = "5";
            }
            else
            {
                txtres.Text = txtres.Text + "5";
            }
        }

        private void btnn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtres.Text == "0")
            {
                txtres.Text = "";
            }
            if (txtres.Text == "")
            {
                txtres.Text = "6";
            }
            else
            {
                txtres.Text = txtres.Text + "6";
            }
        }

        private void btnn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtres.Text == "0")
            {
                txtres.Text = "";
            }
            if (txtres.Text == "")
            {
                txtres.Text = "7";
            }
            else
            {
                txtres.Text = txtres.Text + "7";
            }
        }

        private void btnn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtres.Text == "0")
            {
                txtres.Text = "";
            }
            if (txtres.Text == "")
            {
                txtres.Text = "8";
            }
            else
            {
                txtres.Text = txtres.Text + "8";
            }
        }

        private void btnn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtres.Text == "0")
            {
                txtres.Text = "";
            }
            if (txtres.Text == "")
            {
                txtres.Text = "9";
            }
            else
            {
                txtres.Text = txtres.Text + "9";
            }
        }

        private void btnn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtres.Text == "0")
            {
                txtres.Text = "";
            }
            if (txtres.Text == "")
            {
                txtres.Text = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                txtres.Text = txtres.Text + "0";
            }
        }

        private void txtres_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void frm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtres.Text == "")
            {
                txtres.Text = "0";
            }

        }

        private void btnreinicio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtres.Text = "0";
        }

        private void btndot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtres.Text == "0")
            {
                txtres.Text = "";
            }
            if (txtres.Text.Contains('.') == false) {
                if (txtres.Text == "")
                {
                    txtres.Text = ".";
                }
                else
                {
                    txtres.Text = txtres.Text + ".";
                }
            }
        }

        private void ObtenerValor(string operador) {
            a = Convert.ToDouble(txtres.Text);
            txtres.Text = "0";
        }

        private void btnsuma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operador = Operacion.Suma;
            ObtenerValor("+");
        }



        private void btnresta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operador = Operacion.Resta;
            ObtenerValor("-");
        }

        private void btnmul_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operador = Operacion.Multiplicacion;
            ObtenerValor("*");
        }

        private void btndiv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operador = Operacion.Division;
            ObtenerValor("/");
        }
        private void btnigual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double resultado;
            if (b == 0)
            {
                b = Convert.ToDouble(txtres.Text);
                resultado = HacerOperacion();
                a = 0;
                b = 0;
                txtres.Text = Convert.ToString(resultado);
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo meteria el codigo del boton `btnigual` en una funcion aparte y luego la llamaria cada vez que se pulsase un boton de operacion. De todas formas en ese codigo das muchas vueltas.

Comment: Revisar [answer]

Comment: Mis disculpas, queria meter un comentario, no una respuesta pero me equivoqué. Tengo que familiarizarme un poco todavia con el funcionamiento de la web.

Answer (score 0):

3 cosas para mejorar en tu código + lo que no te sale:

1. Cuando ves que una estructura se repite mucho con poca variación indica que allí tiene que haber una función, es en caso de los números, te propongo la siguiente función siguiendo la lógica de lo que tenías:

   ```
       private void Escribir(string s)//Entrada de caracter
       {

           if (txtres.Text == "0"  || txtres.Text == "") //consulata or debido a que hacen la misma función
           {
               txtres.Text = s;
           }

           else
           {
               txtres.Text = txtres.Text + "1";
           }
       }
   ```
2. Un int 0 es muy probable que te lo escriban, así que no es una buena variable para resetear y declarar como vacía propongo usar lo siguiente:

   ```
   double a = int.MinValue;
   double b = int.MinValue;
   ```

Es menos probable que te lo escriban, ya que es un número muy pequeño.

3. En la función del punto puedes usar `return`; si es de tipo void para salir de la función y mejorar el rendimiento:

   ```
       private void btndot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (txtres.Text == "0")
           {
               txtres.Text = "";
               txtres.Text = ".";
               return;//saca de la función
           }
           if (txtres.Text.Contains('.') == false)
           {
               if (txtres.Text == "")
               {
                   txtres.Text = ".";
               }
               else
               {
                   txtres.Text = txtres.Text + ".";
               }
           }
       }
   ```
4. Para hacer la operación haría la validación y llamar la función igual a obtenerValor la cuestión es sacar la validación cuando a no sea la posición de reseteo o sea doble signo (de cualquier tipo) también puedes sacar el input del tipo, ya que no lo usas:

   ```
   private void ObtenerValor()
   {
       if (a == int.MinValue)
       {
           a = Convert.ToDouble(txtres.Text);
       }
       else
       {
           b = Convert.ToDouble(txtres.Text);
           btnigual_Click(null, new EventArgs());//para llamar funciones asignadas a un botón como click usar esta estructura
       }

       txtres.Text = "0";

   }
   ```

**Codigo Completo:**

```
   public enum Operacion
    {
        NoDefinida = 0,
        Suma = 1,
        Resta = 2,
        Multiplicacion = 3,
        Division = 4
    }
    Operacion operador = Operacion.NoDefinida;
    double a = int.MinValue;
    double b = int.MinValue;



    private double HacerOperacion()
    {
        double resultado = 0;
        switch (operador)
        {
            case Operacion.Suma:
                resultado = a + b;
                break;
            case Operacion.Resta:
                resultado = a - b;
                break;
            case Operacion.Multiplicacion:
                resultado = a * b;
                break;
            case Operacion.Division:
                if (b == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No se puede dividir entre 0");
                    txtres.Text = "0";
                }
                else
                {
                    resultado = a / b;
                }
                break;
        }
        return resultado;

    }
    private void Escribir(string s)
    {
        
        if (txtres.Text == "0"  || txtres.Text == "")
        {
            txtres.Text = s;
        }
      
        else
        {
            txtres.Text = txtres.Text + "1";
        }
    }
    private void btnn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Escribir("1");
    }

    private void btnn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Escribir("2");
    }

    private void btnn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Escribir("3");
    }

    private void btnn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Escribir("4");
    }

    private void btnn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Escribir("5");
    }

    private void btnn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Escribir("6");
    }

    private void btnn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Escribir("7");
    }

    private void btnn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Escribir("8");
    }

    private void btnn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Escribir("9");
    }

    private void btnn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Escribir("0");
    }



    private void frm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtres.Text == "")
        {
            txtres.Text = "0";
        }

    }

    private void btnreinicio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtres.Text = "0";
    }

    private void btndot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtres.Text == "0")
        {
            txtres.Text = "";
            txtres.Text = ".";
            return;
        }
        if (txtres.Text.Contains('.') == false)
        {
            if (txtres.Text == "")
            {
                txtres.Text = ".";
            }
            else
            {
                txtres.Text = txtres.Text + ".";
            }
        }
    }

    private void ObtenerValor()
    {
        if (a == int.MinValue)
        {
            a = Convert.ToDouble(txtres.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            b = Convert.ToDouble(txtres.Text);
            btnigual_Click(null, new EventArgs());
        }
           
        txtres.Text = "0";
       
    }

    private void btnsuma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operador = Operacion.Suma;
        ObtenerValor();
        
    }



    private void btnresta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operador = Operacion.Resta;
        ObtenerValor();
    }

    private void btnmul_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operador = Operacion.Multiplicacion;
        ObtenerValor();
    }

    private void btndiv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operador = Operacion.Division;
        ObtenerValor();
    }
    private void btnigual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double resultado;
        if (b == int.MinValue)
        {
            b = Convert.ToDouble(txtres.Text);
            resultado = HacerOperacion();
            a = int.MinValue;
            b = int.MinValue;
            txtres.Text = Convert.ToString(resultado);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pd: como dijo @realcnk puedes sacar el código función de btnigual y llamar la función en sí cada vez que lo uses

Comment: Y esto como responde la pregunta?? lo lei varias veces, y no logre entender donde esta la respuesta.. igual, la respusta no esta mal, pero hay varias optimizaciones mas para hacer.. ojo cuando hagas este tipo de respustas... por ejemplo hay 10 clicks para botones que deberian ser uno solo... el minimo, no deberia ser el minimo int.. porque tendria que ser ese valor y no un nulo???? == false deberia reemplazarse por un ! delante del booleano. y asi nos podemos pasar toda la tarde... centrate en responder la prgunta, y despus has todas las observaciones que quieras...